# How to alter Laravel ORM save function?

Tags: laravel, orm, eloquent

I use this function to get the values  from a form and to save it to database:

```
public function save($request, $distID)
{
    try {
        $model = Dist::firstOrNew([ 'distID' => $distID ]);
        foreach ($request as $key => $value) {
            $model->{$key} = $value;
        }
        $model->save();
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        return false;
    }
    $lastInsertedId = DB::getPdo()->lastInsertId();
    $return_value = $lastInsertedId === "0" ? $distID : $lastInsertedId;
    return $return_value;
}
```

One of the form input is a password field, the problem is that saves that value to databse as a "pasword" and not as a md5 encripted values. The form is a profile edit form.

So the question is: how to save that value as a md5 values, using the code above?

Solutions I found, and thinking of trying:

-before try, get the request password values and change it with the md5 alternative

-using an insert query

What is the best solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Create a [mutator](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators) method in your model like the one given below:

```
public function setPasswordAttribute($value)
{
    $this->attributes['password'] = md5($value);
}
```

There are other ways like creating an [event](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent#events) handler for saving/creating etc.

---

**Note:** Why not use [Hash::make($value)](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/hashing#basic-usage) instead?

Comment: I am still learning Laravel, will give it a try. thx for answer